# Windows7Pro64bit版でnetshで登録したarpの静的エントリが消えてしまう

Tags: windows, network

タイトルの通りなのですが、なんらかのタイミングで登録したはずのarpの静的キャッシュエントリが消えてしまいます。
OSの起動直後に登録すると登録には成功するのですが、少し立つと消えてしまいます。
その間に起動する自作のソフトはあり、UDPのパケットは送出しますが、arpエントリを消すような動作はもちろん作り込んでいません。
他にはソフトは起動していません。

MSの以下のサイトによればnetshコマンドで登録したarpエントリは永続的に保持されるように見えるのですが、何か消える条件があるのでしょうか。
https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/help/2840421/snmp-trap-is-partly-destroyed-during-arp-execution-in-windows